# How to determine timeout in volley?

Tags: android, android-volley

I want to take different actions when volley time outs or has a network problem (vs when there is a problem on the server).

As I understand both cases will be reported by volley through the same ErrorListener interface.

I have a code currently which parses the message in VolleyError and check for couple of things (search following strings) to determine whether it was timeout/network problem (vs a server error).

- java.net.ConnectException
- java.net.UnknownHostException

However, I am not that happy with this code. First of all, it's hacky. Also, I can easily miss some cases which I am not aware of.

I am wondering whether there is a better way to distinguish these two groups of errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh... I didn't realize there are subclasses, which implement some of Volley errors:

- TimeoutError
- NetworkError
- NoConnectionError

So, instead of checking message, I should be checking a class of an error.